# django core exceptions Improperly Configured:

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>
> The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings.

This is my settings.py file code

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  )

  STATIC_URL = "/static/"
  ROOT_URLCONF = "%s.urls" % PROJECT_DIR
  TEMPLATE_DIRS = full_path("Home/Downloads/django-socketio-master/djangosocketio/templates")
  #LOGIN_URL = "/admin/"
```

Answer (score 3):

seems that path provided to  `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is not correct.
You can provide path like

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../templates'),)
```

where `templates` is directory where your templates resides.